# buildozer - INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE for python code

Tags: android, python

I am using [Buildozer](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) which should make a .apk for me without too many complications.

I wrote a python script using [this library](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface). In other words the python code I wrote has strictly nothing to do with Android, yet I would like to use it on Android as backend/library. The python code I wrote works perfectly fine on my laptop itself.

Buildozer managed to generate a .apk file, but when executing this command on Ubuntu:

```
$ ./adb install myPythonScript.apk
```

I get:

```
myPythonScript.apk: 1 file pushed. 4.1 MB/s (7639867 bytes in 1.766s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/myPythonScript.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU architecture you have built does not match the CPU architecture you are trying to install the application on. If you want to make app for android written in python. I suggest you start with [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)